# iPhone sdk will not compile if i use UITableView Group background color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, grouped-table

if i use grouped table view or just use this color, i get this compilation error:
**The document "DetailedView.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed.  -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil.**

if i use plain tableview it works fine.
also i tested on number of xcode installations and on different computers and still the same.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some more code? I.e. the array you are fetching from and how you are fetching info?

Comment: not using any code, all through Interface Builder

Comment: yeah, it's happening to me too, But when i tried it on another computer it worked for a test application, not the same one that is crashing on my pc. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, i'm doing it programmatically now. So far it's working fine.